# Finding the upper bound on the error with Taylor-Lagrange inegality

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

I have this exercise in my Calculus I homework:

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f (1) = 2$ and that its derivatives $n$ are given by

$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n(n-1)!/(x+2)^n$    where $n>1$.

I need to give an upper bound, in absolute value, on the error made by approximating the function $f (x)$ by $T_1 (x)$ which is valid for all $x$ and belonging to the interval (0.3). My problem is that I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: What's $T_1(x)$ exactly?

Comment: It's the Taylor polynomial of degree 1 and it's near the point a = 1.

Comment: In this case, you have to find an upper bound for $|f''(x)|=\dfrac 1{|x+2|^2}$ when $x\in(0,3)$. What's your difficulty?

Comment: My teacher told us we need to use the Taylor-Lagrange inequality, but I don't know how to find the M in this inequality.

Comment: You can't find an upper bound for $\smash[b]{\dfrac 1{|x+2|^2}}$??? It amounts to finding a lower bound for the denominator (when $ 0<x<3$)

Comment: Yes that sounds right, so I don't understand why the question says upper bound... Anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: An upper bound is required for Taylor-Lagrange inequality, and an upper pound for a fraction means an upperbound for the numerator and/or a lower bound for the denominator. $1/3$ is bigger than $1/4$

Comment: Okay it clarifies it, thank you!